# How can I send $scope variables from a window to a parent window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to write this code in angular:

```
   opener.window.postMessage({code:$scope.variable1,amount:$scope.variable2}."*");
```

How can i write this line of code in Angular?
The child element is written in angular but the code of the parent window is in simple javascript code.
this line of code is executed on the child window.

Answer (score 0):

`postMessage` API suggets to transfer **strings** not objects, therefore you should serialize it.

You can do something like that:

```
opener.window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({code:$scope.variable1,amount:$scope.variable2}), "*");
```